# Php/Mysql multi queries on same file

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Beginner PHP / Mysql here.
I have a file *clientdetails.php*, which uses a GET method to connect to a Mysql database and retrieve data (top half of code below). On the same file, I have bootstrap tabs. On one of these tabs, I would like to run another Mysql query to obtain different data from the same database.

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp64\www\crud\clientdetails.php on line 51
```

I suspect this has something to do with a connection already existing?

This is a simplified version of clientdetails.php:

```
<?php
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["client_id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["client_id"]))){
        // Include config file
        require_once 'config.php';
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id = ?";
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);
            // Set parameters
            $param_id = trim($_GET["client_id"]);
           // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                if($result->num_rows == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id parameter. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
        // Close connection
        $mysqli->close();
    } else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
?>

 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Details</a></li>
</ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="Account" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="form-group">
        <?php
                // Include config file
        require_once 'config.php';
        // Attempt select query execution
        $sql = "SELECT transaction FROM client";
        if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){    
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                    echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<th>#</th>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['client_id'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</tbody>";
                echo "</table>";
                $result2->free();
            } else{
                echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
        }
        // Close connection
        $mysqli->close();
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Config file:

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_NAME', 'mydatabase');
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: show ur config.php

Comment: This has been done

Comment: Don't close the connection maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

- You did require_once config.php, which means, it will only be included once (in the first condition)
- You did close the mysqli connection on the first condition, so mysqli is not accessible anymore after that.

You should not close the connection in the first condition, so you can reuse it in the second condition (tabs). Good practice is to close the connection on the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding a parameter before giving it a value. I have absolutely no idea if that fixes anything tough.

```
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
$stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);
// Set parameters
$param_id = trim($_GET["client_id"]);
```

Should be

```
// Set parameters
$param_id = trim($_GET["client_id"]);
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
$stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);
```